# Android HttpClient to accept all cookies

Tags: android, httpclient, http-get, httpcookie, cookiestore

I'm pretty new in the Android world and maybe my question is very simple..
I have an android app where I use HttpGet to connect to a server and collect data.
However the server sometimes sets some cookies that are not remembered by my code.
I found a post where its using a custom cookie policy and is accepting everything.. just what I need.But I cant implement it.As I understand my version of java httpclient is old and does not have the functions I need.
Here's my code:

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(link);

        get.getParams().setParameter(
                ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get,ctx);
        status_code = responseGet.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();

        if (resEntityGet != null) {
            http_response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
        }

    }
```

And the code I need to implement:

```
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
CookieSpecFactory csf = new CookieSpecFactory() {
    public CookieSpec newInstance(HttpParams params) {
        return new BrowserCompatSpec() {
            @Override
            public void validate(Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
                    throws MalformedCookieException {
                log.debug("allow all cookies");
            }
        };
    }
};
httpclient.getCookieSpecs().register("easy", csf);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
        ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, "easy");
```

All I need is to set this csf policy to my client.
However it seems that I dont have these two functions in the library : setCookieStore and getCookieSpecs().register()

What are my options to run it ?!